# How to return a Map with an Integer key and Set<...>value?

Tags: java

1. I have got this class

   ```
   public class Motorcycle{

    private final Integer year;
    private Integer km;
    public Motorcycle(Integer year, Integer km) {
        super();
        this.year= year;
        this.km = km;
    }
    public Integer getKm() {
        return km;
    }
    public void setKm(Integer km) {
        this.km = km;
    }
    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }
   }
   ```
2. And this class

   ```
   public class Scooter extends Motorcycle{

    public Scooter(Integer year, Integer km) {
        super(year, km);
    }

   }
   ```

In another class I have got

```
private Set<Motorcycle>moto;
public Map<Integer, Set<Motorcycle>> getScooterByYear() {}
```

getScooterByYear is a method which returns a map with an entry whose key is an Integer (the year of registration of the
motorcycles) and by value the set of Scooter-type motorcycles contained in motorcycles whose
year is equal to the key of the corresponding entry.
I have to implement it without parameters.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: And where are you getting this information from? User input? A file? A database? Wikipedia? If the only requirement is that it be "a map containing scooters", then `return new HashMap();` is a great implementation of this function. But I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sorry i forgot to write it.
I started with a:
private Set<Motorcycle> moto;
And i have to make the metod using .stream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that your method gets the base collection as input (that way it doesn't matter where it actually comes from). In that case, your method may also be static.

```
public static Map<Integer, Set<Motorcycle>> getScooterByYear(Collection<Motorcycle> motorcycles) {
    return motorcycles.stream()
                      .filter(m -> m instanceof Scooter)
                      .collect(groupingBy(Motorcycle::getYear, toSet()));
}
```

It should be self-explanatory. First you filter for what you want and then you group the stuff by year and the second argument of `groupingBy` gives you a Set (where List would be the default).

*Disclaimer:* if this was some sort of homework, be advised that your teacher may not accept this answer, because it might be too "modern" for school stuff.

Comment: THANK YOU!
With you suggest i resolved it with this:

public Map<Integer, Set<Motorcycle>> getScooterByYear() {
    return moto.stream()
                    .filter(m -> m instanceof Scooter)
                    .collect(groupingBy(Motorcycle::getYear, Collectors.toSet())); 

 }